# Can't get my Polymorphic relationships working

Tags: php, laravel, oop, polymorphism, relationship

couldn't find any answer on stackoverflow yet, so imma ask it by myself. My polymorphic relationships work kinda weird. I cannot retrieve Comments from the post, but I can retrieve Post from the specific Comment.

My comment:

[image: row]

And here is my code for relationships:

(I am using Thread model as well, but it isn't important in this situation).

POST:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

COMMENT:

```
public function commentable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Websites output when I use `$comments = Post::where('id', 1)->first()->comments;` and then `dd($comments)` :

[image]

**EDIT:**
It seems like adding the comment right on the page helped. Whereas adding the comment manually in phpmyadmin caused problems. Problem solved.

Comment: look at this function `morphTo()` and asses it,  or create your own static function inside  your `Comment` class.

Comment: Tried to change it a bit, changed convention as well but still nothing (works the same way, can get Post of the specific Comment, but cannot get Comment of the specific Post). I want to use it the normal way it is supposed to be used. I'll keep the own static function as the last choice.